# django modeltranslation prefix_default_language

Tags: python, django

i add prefix_default_language = False in urls.py

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    prefix_default_language= False
)
```

but the form for changing the language stopped working for the default language

form:

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
        <select name="language">
            {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
            {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
            {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
            {% for language in languages %}
                <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                        selected{% endif %}>
                    {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                </option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

how fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Add to settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE='en' #required language
```

Comment: why would it help?

Comment: I find this soution somewhere and it helped me. It works for me.